# Azure Databricks is unable to create an Event Grid Subscription for Autoloader Streams

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-autoloader

I am trying to create an autoloader stream in Azure Databricks.
Now when I am trying to start the writeStream, I am presented with exception saying:

> `com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesException: Failed to create an Event Grid subscription. Please make sure that your service principal has 'write' permissions (e.g., assign it a Contributor role) on the storage account rahulstorageek in order to create Event Grid Subscriptions`

[image]

Following is the code I am using:

```
# spark and cloudFiles configurations
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<My ADLS Gen2 Storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net",
               "<Access Key 2 of my Storage Account>")
 
queuesas = "<SAS Connection String for Queue Storage>"
 
cloudfilesConf = {
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId": "<Azure Free Trial Subscription Id>",
    "cloudFiles.connectionString": queuesas,
    "cloudFiles.format" : "csv",
    "cloudFiles.tenantId": "<Service Principals tenant Id>",
    "cloudFiles.clientId": "<Service Principals client Id>",
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret": "<Service Principals generated client secret Value>",
    "cloudFiles.resourceGroup" : "AzureDataBricks_Exploration_RG",
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications": "true",
    "cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles": "true",
    "cloudFiles.validateOptions": "true",
}

# Creating manual schema of incoming data
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
 
dataset_schema = StructType([
    StructField("YearsExperience", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("Salary", IntegerType(), True)])


# Autoloader ReadStream
autoloader_df = (spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
      .options(**cloudfilesConf)
      .option("recursiveFileLookup","true")
      .schema(dataset_schema)
      .load("/mnt/autoloadersource/csv_files/")
      )

# Autoloader Writestream
(autoloader_df.writeStream
 .format("delta")
 .option("mergeSchema", "true")
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/autoloadersink/autostream_chckpnt")
 .start("/mnt/autoloadersink/autoloader_dt01"))
## Exception is raised after executing this above command.
```

I have given following roles to the service principal I am using.
[image]

Additionally the SAS token I generated for Queue were with the following parameters:
[image]

I have tried giving all the additional roles to service principal you could see in the above screenshots but, still I am getting the same error.

Any solutions or suggestions would be highly valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions isn't enough because event grid needs to be created.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/file-notification-mode#permissions-azure) clearly specify the necessary roles:

- on storage account you need:

  - `Contributor` - will be used setting up resources in your storage account, such as queues and event subscriptions.
  - `Storage Queue Data Contributor`: will be used to perform queue operations such as retrieving and deleting messages from the queues. (May not be required if you use DBR 8.1+ and provide connection string).
- On resource group:

  - `EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor`: will be used to perform event grid subscription operations.